# Difference between heap memory and string pool

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between heap memory and string pool in Java?

[in this link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-String-s1-Hello-and-String-s1-new-String-Hello-in-Java) , it is said that:

```
String s1 = "Hello";

String s2 = new String("Hello");
```

s1 points to String Pool's location
and
s2 points to Heap Memory location.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**StringPool** is an area that the JVM uses to avoid redundant generation of String objects..

Those objects there can be "recycled" so you can (re)use them and so avoiding the "waste" of too much memory...

Consider the following example:

```
String s1 = "cat";

String s2 = "cat";

String s3 = new String("cat");
```

the **JVM** is smart enough to see that the object **s2** is going to be assigned with the value "cat" which is already allocated in the memory(and assigned to the object "s1"), so instead of creating a new object and wasting that new memory place, it assign the reference to the same memory allocated for **s1**

[image]

Comment: plus for the image

Comment: When instantiating a string which method should I use `""` vs `new`? Is there a pitfall I should watch out for using either of those?

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 9):

When you use `String s = "Hello"; Sting s2= "Hello"` you get the same copy for both `s` and `s2`. However, when you do `String s = new String("Hello"); String s2 = new String("Hello")` you have different copies for `s` and `s2` in the heap.