# String class object

Tags: java, string, class, object

There is a rule in Java, that to create any object of class we have to use 'new' keyword, but when we use String class,we can create object as

```
String s = "hello";
```

so we haven't used new as an operator still new object has been created in String constant pool in heap!
Can anyone explain how we created an object without using new keyword!

Comment: `"hello"` is a `String` [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming))

Comment: Java language designers are free to build any "magic" into the compiler. Creating objects without `new` keyword is one of these. Another situation when an object is created without `new` keyword is autoboxing.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908347/5675692)

Comment: The ClassLoader delivered a String. Actually "hello" is stored as UTF-8 string in the .class using it.

Comment: This is a String literal - a fixed value in **source code**. So it's done on compilation (checking with pool).

Comment: So in heap memory, there are two partition, one is String constant pool and another is heap (non constant) pool. Am i right? Correct me if i am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Comparision of string initialization performance for `String Literal` and `String object`. :

**String Literal**
`String str = “Hello”;`

This is string literal. When you declare string like this, you are actually calling intern() method on String. This method references internal pool of string objects. If there already exists a string value “Hello”, then str will reference of that string and no new String object will be created.

**String Object**
`String str = new String(“Hello”);`

This is string object. In this method JVM is forced to create a new string reference, even if “Hello” is in the reference pool.

Comment: Got your point, just need bit more understanding about string constant pool and heap pool

Comment: So in heap memory, there are two partition, one is String constant pool and another is heap (non constant) pool. Am i right? Correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: For clarity: The seven characters `"Hello"` make up a String literal, in both cases. `str` is a variable containing a String object, in both cases. `new String("Hello")` picks up the object defined by the literal and makes another object from it. Also, be careful when pasting code into Stack Overflow: this code cannot be compiled because the quotes are not 'QUOTATION MARK' (U+0022).