# How many objects will be created in string pool?

Tags: java, string, object, heap-memory

How many objects will be created in the following Java code:

```java
String s = "abc";
s = "";
String s2 = new String("mno");
s2 = "pqr";
```

Comment: What language is this? Add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908347/10819573) which describes it using a good diagram that you can remember. The duplicate link there also takes you to very good answers.

Comment: Also, don't miss this [useful comment by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481998/check-if-a-variable-is-in-the-string-constant-pool#comment105140425_59481998) and the answer by Stephen C.

Comment: Thanks for help @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `String s = "abc";` → one object, that goes into the string pool, as the literal "abc" is used;
2. `s = "";` → one empty string (`""`) object, and again - allocated in the string pool;
3. `String s2 = new String("mno");` → another object created with an explicit `new` keyword, and note, that it actually involves *yet another* literal object (again - created in the string pool) - `"mno"`; overall, two objects here;
4. `s2 = "pqr";` → yet another object, being stored into the string pool.

So, there are 5 objects in total; 4 in the string pool (a.k.a. "intern pool"), and one in the ordinary heap.

Remember, that anytime you use `"string literal"`, JVM first checks whether the same string object (according to `String::equals..()`) exists in the string pool, and it then does one of the following:

1. If corresponding string does not exist, JVM creates a string object and puts it in the string pool. That string object is a candidate to be reused, by JVM, anytime equal to it (again, according to `String::equals(..)`) string literal is referenced (without explicit `new`);
2. If corresponding string exists, its reference is just being returned, without creating anything new.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @GiorgiTsiklauri